# Add div on mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I need to show the div when user clicked on the add another member button. User can add only 5 members so How do I make the action to generate the particular div only five times?

This is the div which needs to be displayed on click. But not cloning because I need to add different name attribute for all the text boxes for the validation.

```
<div class="loop">
   <input type="text" value="first name" />
   <input type="text" value="lastname" />
   <input type="text" value="mail" />
   <input type="text" value="company" />
</div>

<button>Add person</button>
```

I need the same div to be generated when clicked on the button. But maximum they can create only 5 times.

Comment: Hints: `.clone()`, `.length < 5`

Comment: Do you have any JS code that you can show?

Comment: @Sowmya , please check my answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will clone div's and adds `name` attribute to all of inputs inside this div,with a `name=value+id`:  **DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/R5urc/

```
 <div class='parentDiv'>   
    <div class="loop">
       <input type="text" value="first name" />
       <input type="text" value="lastname" />
       <input type="text" value="mail" />
       <input type="text" value="company" />
  </div>
```

Your button:

```
<button id='add' onclick='addPerson()'>Add person</button>
```

JS code :

```
 <script type='text/javascript'

     function addPerson(){

        if ($('div.loop').length<5) {

           var clonedDiv=$($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo('.parentDiv');

           clonedDiv.find('input').each(function() {
             $(this).attr('name',$(this).val()+$('div.loop').length);
           });

        }

     }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @techfoobar said the clone function of jQuery would be your solution here.

Here is the HTML that would facilitate this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="loop">
        <input type="text" value="first name" />
        <input type="text" value="lastname" />
        <input type="text" value="mail" />
        <input type="text" value="company" />
    </div>
</div>
<button>Add person</button>
```

Javascript needed:

```
clicks = 0;
$('button').on('click', function () {
    if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
        clicks++;
        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
        $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).attr('value', $(element).attr('value') + clicks);
        });
    }
});
```

Working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/wRJAe/3/

Comment: @FaceOfJock oh yes.. I dont want this to clone the name attr as well.

Comment: yes that s pretty nice idea. BUt how can it be done in jquery??

Comment: This is now working and updated.  According to @FaceOfJock's suggestion.
http://jsfiddle.net/wRJAe/3/

Comment: @Sowmya i added my own solution too

Answer (score 0):

here you can set the text box values dynamically

```
   <div class="main_loop">    
        <div class="loop" style="display:none;">
           <input type="text" value="first name" />
           <input type="text" value="lastname" />
           <input type="text" value="mail" />
           <input type="text" value="company" />
        </div> 
    </div>

        <div class="main">
        </div>

        <button>Add person</button>


$('button').on('click', function () {
   if ($('.main .loop').length < 5) {
     $('.main_loop .loop').clone().appendTo(".main").show();

     $(".main .loop:nth-child("+$('.main .loop').length+")").children().each(function(){

         $(this).val($(this).val()+$('.main .loop').length);
     });
    }
});
```